# restartBrowserBetweenTests does not restart browser, only closes it

Tags: cucumber, protractor, cucumberjs

I am trying to run multiple tests within a feature file (multiple scenarios). In between each scenario I need the browser to restart (or at least a new window be used). I try setting `restartBrowserBetweenTests: true` but for some reason it just causes the browser to close after the first scenario and never opens a new one. I am using protractor-cucumber.

This is my conf file:

```
exports.config = {

  specs: [
    'wordAssessTimer.feature'
  ],

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  },

  // Framework to use. 
  framework: 'cucumber',

  allScriptsTimeout: 300000,

  // Options to be passed to cucumber
  cucumberOpts: {
        require: ['steps.js', 'reporter.js'],
        format: 'pretty',
        strict: true
      },

  restartBrowserBetweenTests: true
};
```

This is my package file:

```
{
  "name": "wordAssessTimer",
  "version": "",
  "description": "",
  "main": "conf.js",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cucumber": "0.4.9",
    "protractor": "2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": ""
}
```

I cannot post the steps or feature file for confidentiality reasons, however there is nothing there that should prevent a new browser from being opened.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I see that a new browser window or browser tab should suffice as well. I discourage you from closing the browser, since the user might have some tabs opened, which upon browser close would lose data. For instance, if the user has a browser tab open where he writes a forum post and has written 2000 characters already, then when the browser closes, he will lose all his data entered there. I suggest a much less frustrating solution, using the [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) javascript function, which, depending on the browser will either open a new tab or a new browser window. Also, you can reload the page with

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Comment: I'm doing this from within protractor, so I don't have a window handle to call window.open on :/